# Reference to inner product on Galois Extension

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was reading a paper on which they defined an inner product 
The number field $\mathbb{K}$ (or $\mathbb{L}$) is viewed as a Euclidean $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space by endowing it with the inner product
$\langle a, b \rangle $ =$\sum_{i=1}^{n}e(a)\bar e(b) $
where $e$ ranges over all the $n$ embeddings K → C. Can anyone provide me the reference and the general material or background from which this definition has been taken from.

The paper is -[Source](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/127.pdf)  Page 7

Comment: I moved the bar in the formula so that it would be over the $e$, as it ought to be. Hope you don’t mind. (if you want the bar over the whole “$e(b)$”, use \overline.)